# How to end the incoming phone call programmatically specially on devices API level 25,26,27

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, telephonymanager

I am working on an android application where I do intercept the incoming phone call and ending it programmatically on some user action.
To achieve that have used `ITelephony.endCall`.

This implementation works fine only till API level 24.

```
private void rejectCallViaTelephonyManager() {
    ITelephony telephonyService = getTelephonyService();
    if (telephonyService != null) {
        telephonyService.endCall();
    }
}

private ITelephony getTelephonyService() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I also came across new API `TelecomManager.endCall` which got introduced in API level 28. which works fine for P beta device.

```
private void rejectCall() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P /* 28 */) {
            TelecomManager manager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
            if (manager != null) {
                // complains required API app requires API level 28 (current min is 21).
                manager.endCall();
            }
        } else {
            rejectCallViaTelephonyManager();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "call ended successfully.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Now I am looking for solution to make it work for API level 25,26,27 too**.

Any idea how can we do that ?

My goal is to "end incoming phone call" functionality should work for all the version API level 21 onward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I archived this and also work on android P version.
First of all.
Manifest Permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Now on API greater than 21 ask users to give runtime permissions in code also.
if lower than oreo then ask like this.

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},REQUEST_CONTACTS);
```

But if greater than oreo then.

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},REQUEST_CONTACTS);
```

Now create a complete package in your app like this.

```
com.android.internal.telephony
```

In this package place this interface.

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;
public interface ITelephony {
boolean endCall();
void answerRingingCall();
void silenceRinger();
}
```

Now end call like this.

```
 private void endCall(){
 ITelephony telephonyService;
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (tm == null)
        return;
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        if (telecomManager != null) {
            telecomManager.endCall();
        }
    } else {

        if (telephonyService != null) {
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.endCall();
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you for addressing the question, but this is same as how I tried .There is no change. The only issue I have is end API call **TelecomManager and TelePhonyManager** doesn't work only for the devices API level 25,26,27. Thanks again!!